# Most efficient way to join to a two-part key, with a fallback to matching only the first part?

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2012, internationalization

**In purely technical terms**

Given a table with a two-column unique key, and input values for those two columns, what is the most efficient way to return the first matching row based on a **two-step** match?:

1. If an exact match exists on both key parts, return that
2. Otherwise, return the first (if any) matching row based on the first part alone

This operation will be done in many different places, on many rows. The "payload" of the match will be a single string column (`nvarchar(400)`). I want to optimize for fast reads. Paying for this with slower inserts and updates and more storage is acceptable. So having multiple indexes with the payload [`include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)d is an option, as long is there is a good way to execute the two-step match described above. There absolutely will be a unique index on `(key1, key2)` with the payload `include`d, so essentially all reads will be going off of this index alone, unless there is some clever approach that would use additional indexes.

A method that returns the entire matching row is preferred, but if a scalar function that only returns the payload is an order of magnitude faster, then that is worth considering.

I've tried three different methods, two of which I have posted as answers below. The third method was about 20x more expensive in the explain plan cost, and I've included it at the end of this post as an example of what not to do.

I'm curious to see if there are better ways, though, and will happily vote someone else's suggestion as the answer if it is better. In my dev database the query planner estimates similar costs to my two approaches, but my dev database doesn't have anywhere near the volume of multilingual text that will be in production, so it's hard to know if this accurately reflects the comparative read performance on a large data set. As tagged, the platform is SQL Server 2012, so if there are new applicable features available as of that version do make use of them.

**Business context**

I have a table `LabelText` that represents translations of user-supplied dynamic content:

```
create table Label  ( bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key );

create table LabelText (
    LabelTextID         bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key
  , LabelID             bigint not null
  , LanguageCode        char(2) not null
  , LabelText           nvarchar(400) not null        
  , constraint FK_LabelText_Label
    foreign key ( NameLabelID ) references Label ( LabelID )
);
```

There is a unique index on `LabelID` and `LanguageCode`, so there can only be one translation of a text item for each ISO 2-character language code. The `LabelText` field is also `include`d, so reads can access the index along without having to fetch back from the underlying table:

```
create unique index UQ_LabelText 
    on LabelText ( LabelID, LanguageCode )
    include ( LabelText);
```

I'm looking for the fastest-performing way to return the best match from the `LabelText` table in a two-step match, given a `LabelID` and `LanguageCode`.

For examples, let's say we have a `Component` table that looks like this:

```
create table Component ( 
    ComponentID         bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key
  , NameLabelID         bigint not null
  , DescriptionLabelID  bigint not null
  , constraint FK_Component_NameLabel
    foreign key ( NameLabelID ) references Label ( LabelID )
  , constraint FK_Component_DescLabel
    foreign key ( DescriptionLabelID ) references Label ( LabelID )        
);
```

Users will each have a preferred language, but there is no guarantee that a text item will have a translation in their language. In this business context it makes more sense to show *any* available translation rather than none, when the user's preferred language is not available. So for example a German user may call a certain widget the 'linkenpfostenklammer'. A British user would prefer to see an English translation if one is available, but until there is one it is better to see the German (or Spanish, or French) version than to see nothing.

**What not to do: Cross apply with dynamic sort**

Whether encapsulated in a table-valued function or included inline, the following use of cross apply with a dynamic sort was about 20x more expensive (per explain plan estimate) than either the scalar-valued function in my first answer or the union all approach in my second answer:

```
declare @LanguageCode char(2) = 'de';

select
    c.ComponentID
  , c.NameLabelID 
  , n.LanguageCode as NameLanguage
  , n.LabelText    as NameText
from Component c
    outer apply (
        select top 1
            lt.LanguageCode
          , lt.LabelText 
        from LabelText lt
        where lt.LabelID = c.NameLabelID
        order by
            (case when lt.LanguageCode = @LanguageCode then 0 else 1 end)      
    ) n
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is going to be most performant

```
select lt.*, c.* 
  from ( select LabelText, LabelID from LabelText
          where LabelTextID = @LabelTextID and LabelID = @LabelID  
          union 
         select LabelText, min(LabelID)   from LabelText
          where LabelTextID = @LabelTextID 
            and not exists (select 1 from LabelText
                             where LabelTextID = @LabelTextID and LabelID = @LabelID)
          group by LabelTextID, LabelText 
        ) lt 
   join component c 
     on c.NameLabelID = lt.LabelID
```

Comment: Did you test this?  How did it perform?

Answer (score 0):

**OP solution 1: Scalar function**

A scalar function would make it easy to encapsulate the lookup for reuse elsewhere, though it does not return the language code of the text actually returned. I'm also unsure of the cost of executing multiple times per row in denormalized views.

```
create function GetLabelText(@LabelID bigint, @LanguageCode char(2)) 
returns nvarchar(400)
as
begin
    declare @text nvarchar(400);

    select @text = LabelText
    from LabelText
    where LabelID = @LabelID and LanguageCode = @LanguageCode
    ;

    if @text is null begin
        select @text = LabelText
        from LabelText
        where LabelID = @LabelID;
    end

    return @text;
end
```

Usage would look like this:

```
declare @LanguageCode char(2) = 'de';

select
    ComponentID
  , NameLabelID
  , DescriptionLabelID
  , GetLabelText(NameLabelID, @LanguageCode) AS NameText
  , GetLabelText(DescriptionLabelID, @LanguageCode) AS DescriptionText
from Component
```

Answer (score 0):

**OP solution 2: Inline table-valued function using top 1, union all**

A table-valued function is nice because it encapsulates the lookup for reuse just as with a scalar function, but also returns the matching `LanguageCode` of the row that was actually selected. In my dev database with limited data the explain plan cost of the following use of `top 1` and `union all` is comparable to the scalar function approach in "OP Solution 1":

```
create function GetLabelText(@LabelID bigint, @LanguageCode char(2)) 
returns table
as 
return (
    select top 1
        A.LanguageCode
      , A.LabelText
    from (
        select 
            LanguageCode
          , LabelText 
        from LabelText 
        where LabelID = @LabelID 
          and LanguageCode = @LanguageCode

        union all

        select 
            LanguageCode
          , LabelText 
        from LabelText 
        where LabelID = @LabelID  
    ) A
);
```

Usage:

```
declare @LanguageCode char(2) = 'de';

select
    c.ComponentID
  , c.NameLabelID
  , n.LanguageCode AS NameLanguage
  , n.LabelText    AS NameText
  , c.DescriptionLabelID 
  , c.LanguageCode AS DescriptionLanguage
  , c.LabelText    AS DescriptionText
from Component c
    outer apply GetLabelText(c.NameLabelID, @LanguageCode) n
    outer apply GetLabelText(c.DescriptionLabelID, @LanguageCode) d
```